# Questions about MySQL Community Edition (The free Edition)

Tags: mysql

1- Does MySQL Community Edition (The free Edition) supports the following:

- More than one CPU?
- Full-text search?
- Reporting services?

2- What is the size of the database? For example SQL Server Express allow to store 10 GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> More than one CPU?

Yes.

> Full-text search?

Yes.

> Reporting services?

There isn't really a hard and fast equivalent functionality to MSSQL's reporting services - some options are outlined in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582381/mysql-open-source-reporting-services).

> What is the [maximum] size of the database?

Many terabytes - there isn't a license limit like you'd see with SQL Server.  An InnoDB table (individual table, not database) has a maximum size of 64 TB.

Comment: Are you sure about the last point? (The size of the database) do you mean the free edition of MySQL? How did you know that?

Comment: @Joori It's not the kind of "free" where you get a crippled version for free, and fork out for the full featured one - it's the kind of "free" where the product is open source.  Enterprise edition gives you some tools like the enterprise monitor and the cluster manager, but it's not core database functionality.

Comment: @Joori, "How did you know that?" - Shane probably took a few moments to read up about it, as you should have done before asking your questions.